# Find a main element based on value of child element, then change value of different child element

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml file with this structure:

```
<PARENT>
    <LIBRARY>
        <BOOKS>
            <BOOK>
                <BOOK_DATA>
                    <BOOK_TITLE>HOBBIT</BOOK_TITLE>
                </BOOK_DATA>
                <STATUS>NotRead</STATUS>
            </BOOK>
            <BOOK>
                <BOOK_DATA>
                    <BOOK_TITLE>LOTR_FOTR</BOOK_TITLE>
                </BOOK_DATA>
                <STATUS>NotRead</STATUS>
            </BOOK>
            <BOOK>
                <BOOK_DATA>
                    <BOOK_TITLE>LOTR_TT</BOOK_TITLE>
                </BOOK_DATA>
                <STATUS>NotRead</STATUS>
            </BOOK>
            <BOOK>
                <BOOK_DATA>
                    <BOOK_TITLE>LOTR_ROTK</BOOK_TITLE>
                </BOOK_DATA>
                <STATUS>NotRead</STATUS>
            </BOOK>
        </BOOKS>
    </LIBRARY>
</PARENT>
```

Using a powershell script, I'm needing to find the BOOK element containing $BookTitle, then change the value of the STATUS element to $NewStatus

Example:

$BookTitle = LOTR_TT

$NewStatus = Read

Finds:

```
        <BOOK>
            <BOOK_DATA>
                <BOOK_TITLE>LOTR_TT</BOOK_TITLE>
            </BOOK_DATA>
            <STATUS>NotRead</STATUS>
        </BOOK>
```

And changes it to:

```
        <BOOK>
            <BOOK_DATA>
                <BOOK_TITLE>LOTR_TT</BOOK_TITLE>
            </BOOK_DATA>
            <STATUS>Read</STATUS>
        </BOOK>
```

I have the following in StatusChanger.ps1 but it doesn't produce the expected results:

```
param ($BookTitle = LOTR_TT)
param ($NewStatus = Read)
param ($FilePath = C:\file.xml)

#Open the file
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $FilePath

$xml.parent.library.books.book | where { $_.book_data.book_title -like "$BookTitle" } | ForEach {
$_.STATUS = '$NewStatus'
}

#Save the updated file
$xml.Save($FilePath)
```

Comment: When the values of `$BookTitle` and `$NewStatus` are quoted it works for me.. Unquoted, it produces error: `The term 'LOTR_TT' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`. Is that your unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest finding the element by Tagname. Then you to go higher up the hierarchy to access the corresponding status of the Book.

Then it's easy to set the status.

```
$foundedElement = $test.GetElementsByTagName("BOOK_TITLE") |Where-Object {$_."#text" -eq $BookTitle}

$foundedElement.ParentNode.ParentNode.STATUS = $NewStatus

$test.Save($fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `XPath` for this problem:

```
[xml]$xml = ' ... '

$bookTitle = 'LOTR_TT'
$newStatus = 'Read'
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//BOOK[BOOK_DATA/BOOK_TITLE='$bookTitle']/STATUS")
$node.'#text' = $newStatus
```

The important part here is the filter:

```
//BOOK[BOOK_DATA/BOOK_TITLE='$bookTitle']/STATUS
```

This will pick the `STATUS` node off the book matching the filter `BOOK_TITLE='$bookTitle'` and powershell exposes `InnerText` as the `#text` property.

---

Used in your example script:

```
param(
    [string]
    $BookTitle = 'LOTR_TT',

    [string]
    $NewStatus = 'Read',

    [string]
    $FilePath = 'C:\file.xml'
)

[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $FilePath

$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//BOOK[BOOK_DATA/BOOK_TITLE='$BookTitle']/STATUS")
$node.'#text' = $NewStatus

$xml.Save($FilePath)
```

---

Alternatively so, if you want to find ALL nodes that contain a string to change to read, you can do the following:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//BOOK[BOOK_DATA/BOOK_TITLE[contains(., '$BookTitle')]]/STATUS") |
    ForEach-Object { $_.'#text' = $NewStatus }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there are two errors in your code:

1. you should quote the values for `$BookTitle` and `$NewStatus`, so they become
   `$BookTitle = 'LOTR_TT'` and `$NewStatus = 'Read'`
2. you are single quoting this: `$_.STATUS = '$NewStatus'` and by doing so you set the STATUS to the **literal** value of "$NewStatus". Remove those quotes to insert the **Value** of the variable:

   `$_.STATUS = $NewStatus`

After that if works fine for me.